# Re-use tableview from different controller: how to split didSelectRowAtIndexPath behaviour?

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently working on my Favorites implementation. In the end, it should work the same as the favorites features in the Phone book on the iPhone.

I've the following set-up (besides other controllers and classes):

- TabBarController (named mainTabBarController)
- NavigationController with a Tableview (let's call it listNavController)
- ViewController with some components for displaying row details (named detailViewController)
- NavigationController with a TableView for favorite records (named favoritesNavController)

From the *favoritesNavController*, I want to select a row (from *listNavController*) so I can add a new entry to my Favorites tableview.

So, I decided to re-use my *listNavController* because it has all the functionality I need. Like searching, index, etc.

I've managed to show the *listNavController* from the *mainTabBarController*. So no problem here. When I select a row from the *listNavController*, it displays my *detailViewController* for that row. Of course, this was expected because that's in *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* in *listNavController*.

But, when I launch a *listNavController* from my *favoritesNavController* with the help of *presentModelViewController*, it still shows the *detailViewController* when selecting a row.

In this case, I want to return the selected row to my *favoritesNavController*. Then I can add it to my Favorite's list.

So, how do I differentiate this behaviour in code ? Should I use protocols, delegation, etc. ?

Any tips ?

With regards,

Rutger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was looking in the wrong direction.

The solution to the posted question is as follows:

I created a subclass of my listNavController and overrided the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Next I presented this new view controller with a navigation controller as a modal view (presentModalViewController).

Finally I set the delegate and a protocol for the subclassed view controller to the initiating class. This way I can present and dismiss the subclassed view controller from the same controller. A much more clean and MVC way to go!